# Produce a truth table set of n values, but I have only one problem

Tags: python, recursion, typeerror, truthtable, helpermethods

```
def make_tt_ins(n):
   if n == 0:
      return []
   elif n == 1:
      return [False, True]
   else:
      prev_set = make_tt_ins(n - 1)
      full_set = cross_multiply(prev_set, [False, True])
      return full_set

def cross_multiply(s1, s2):
   rtn_set = []
   for i in range(len(s1)):
      for j in range(len(s2)):
         if type(s1[i]) == bool:
            nxt = [s1[i], s2[j]]
            rtn_set.append(nxt)
         else:
            nxt = []
            for x in range(len(s1[i])):
               nxt.append(s1[i][x])
               nxt.append(s2[j])
            rtn_set.append(nxt)
   return rtn_set
```

The above code is something that I've been able to make in python language. The point of this function is to return a list of the truth table given a number of values(n).
ex. [[False, False], [False, True], [True, False], [True, True]] if n=2.
This all works out perfectly fine for me, but when I am going to turn it in for my project, apparently calling make_tt_ins(n) with n=1, I get a "TypeError: 'bool object is not iterable", however when n is any other value, it works out just fine and without a problem. I even tested it before and after with n=1 and I still don't get an issue. I was wondering if anyone can help me understand what this is happening!

Comment: `make_tt_ins(1)` doesn't produce any error for me.

Comment: Is this for an assignment or are you open to a more efficient (one-liner) code? ;)

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark the name of the second function seemed to be a test one, I corrected it, runs fine for me

Comment: @mozway How did you change it to produce an error? I don't see how `make_tt_ins(1)` could produce an error since it's a base case.

Comment: Also if this isn't a homework assignment, `itertools.product([True, False], repeat=2**(n - 1))` will produce what you're looking for for you (as mozway was hinting at). However, I would suggest against turning this in if this was an assignment for obvious reasons.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark yes but not exactly ;) `repeat=2**(n-1)`

Comment: @mozway Ah yeah, thanks for pointing that out.